# Projection operator in Banach space is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $(X,||\cdot ||)$ be a Banach space with a Schauder basis, i.e. there exist $e_j \in X$, $j\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. $||e_j||=1$ for all $j$ and every $x\in X$ can be uniquely represented as $x=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j e_j$ for some scalars $\alpha_j$'s. Show that the linear functional $f_k \left( \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j e_j \right) := \alpha_k$ is continuous without using Banach Isomorphism Theorem (BIT).

Note that BIT gives you that $f_k$'s are in fact *uniformly bounded* with respect to $k$, because defining $|||x|||:= \sup_n \left| \left| \sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j e_j \right| \right| $ you can show it is a norm, that $X$ is complete with this norm and, as $||x||\leq |||x|||$ for all $x$, you can use BIT (with respect to the identity mapping) to get $|||x|||\leq M ||x||$ for all $x$, from which $||f_k||_{X^*} \leq 2M$ follows by writing $\alpha_k \leq \left| \left| \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j e_j - \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \alpha_j e_j \right| \right| \leq 2|||x||| \leq 2M||x||$ (see e.g. R. E. Megginson "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory", pp. 350-356).

I believe that there must be a more straightforward way of showing it; note for instance how easy it is to show it for $l^p$ spaces ($1\leq p \leq \infty $), where you get $||f_k||_{X^*}\leq 1$ by half a line.

Comment: what is obviously bounded is for any closed subspace $A \subset X$ :  $g_A(x) = \arg\!\min_{y \in A} \| y - x\|$, so if you can prove $f_k(x) e_k  = g_{ \langle e_k \rangle}(x) + \mathcal{O}(||x||)$ you are good

Comment: and do you really think $f_k(\sum_j \alpha_j e_j) = \alpha_k $ as you defined it, is **linear** for every $k$ ?  don't you think this implies $\|\sum_j \alpha_j e_j\| = \sum_j \|\alpha_j e_j\|$ ?

Comment: I would doubt it. All proofs I've seen of this proceed along the same lines. The argument is due to Banach himself. In Singer's monograph *Bases in Banach Spaces*, he emphasizes that the "Inversion Theorem of Banach has played a decisive role".

Comment: @DavidMitra you would doubt of what ?